# Deciding the value in console log based on the column value

Tags: javascript, jqwidget

Please take a look at my code below. I have a `YearEligible` column with `Y` and `N` values in the cell for each record. Based on this I want to decide what values does the `Year` column sends upon clicking `Get rows` button.

**Explanation in detail regarding my requirement:**

Let's say If I have checked the very first row ( as shown in the image below):
[image]

When I click on the `Get rows` button, I can see the following in `console.log` which looks good:

```
[{
  available: true,
  boundindex: 0,
  firstname: "Mayumi",
  lastname: "Nagase",
  price: 3.25,
  productname: "Espresso con Panna",
  quantity: 6,
  total: 19.5,
  uid: 0,
  uniqueid: "2128-24-28-17-311629",
  visibleindex: 0,
  yeareligible: "Y",
  yearValue: "2011"
}]
```

However, let's say if I select a record where the `Year Eligible` column has a value of `N` and click on the `Get rows` button, I see the following in `console.log`:

```
[{
  available: true,
  boundindex: 1,
  firstname: "Regina",
  lastname: "Davolio",
  price: 3.3,
  productname: "Doubleshot Espresso",
  quantity: 8,
  total: 26.4,
  uid: 1,
  uniqueid: "2917-25-23-18-212828",
  visibleindex: 1,
  yeareligible: "N"
}]
```

**My observation:**

The above `console.log` is not returning anything for `yearValue`, which makes sense since I didn't select anything.

**My Questions:**

1. In above scenario, is it possible to return a default value of `yearValue` as `-1` ? Basically I want to include `yearValue` as `-1` when a user selects a record with `Year Eligible` value set to `N`.
2. Display N/A on the cell under `Year` column for which the `Year Eligible` column has a value of `N` ?

```js
  var data = new Array();
  var firstNames = [
      "Andrew", "Nancy", "Shelley", "Regina", "Yoshi", "Antoni", "Mayumi", "Ian", "Peter", "Lars", "Petra", "Martin", "Sven", "Elio", "Beate", "Cheryl", "Michael", "Guylene"];
  var lastNames = [
      "Fuller", "Davolio", "Burke", "Murphy", "Nagase", "Saavedra", "Ohno", "Devling", "Wilson", "Peterson", "Winkler", "Bein", "Petersen", "Rossi", "Vileid", "Saylor", "Bjorn", "Nodier"];
      var yearEligible = [
      "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N"];
  var productNames = [
      "Black Tea", "Green Tea", "Caffe Espresso", "Doubleshot Espresso", "Caffe Latte", "White Chocolate Mocha", "Cramel Latte", "Caffe Americano", "Cappuccino", "Espresso Truffle", "Espresso con Panna", "Peppermint Mocha Twist"];
  var priceValues = [
      "2.25", "1.5", "3.0", "3.3", "4.5", "3.6", "3.8", "2.5", "5.0", "1.75", "3.25", "4.0"];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var row = {};
      var productindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * productNames.length);
      var price = parseFloat(priceValues[productindex]);
      var quantity = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
      row["firstname"] = firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)];
      row["lastname"] = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
      row["yeareligible"]= yearEligible[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
      row["productname"] = productNames[productindex];
      row["available"] = !!(i % 2);
      row["price"] = price;
      row["quantity"] = quantity;
      row["total"] = price * quantity;
      data[i] = row;
  }
  var source = {
      localdata: data,
      datatype: "array"
  };
  var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
      loadComplete: function (data) {},
      loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {}
  });
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
      theme: 'energyblue',
      width: 500,
      autoheight: true,
      editable: true,
      source: dataAdapter,
      columns: [{
          text: 'Available',
          datafield: 'available',
          width: 100,
          columntype: 'checkbox'
      }, {
          text: 'First Name',
          datafield: 'firstname',
          width: 100
      }, {
          text: 'Last Name',
          datafield: 'lastname',
          width: 100
      }, {
          text: 'Year Eligible',
          datafield: 'yeareligible',
          width: 100
      },
       {
          text: 'Year',width: 120,datafield:'yearValue' , columntype: 'dropdownlist', editable: true,
          createeditor: function (row, column, editor) {
                    var list = ['2010', '2011', '2012' ,'2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020','2021'];
                  
                   
                     
                    editor.jqxDropDownList({ autoDropDownHeight: true, source: list, selectedIndex: 0 });
                }
       
      },
      {
          text: 'Product',
          datafield: 'productname',
          width: 180
      }, {
          text: 'Quantity',
          datafield: 'quantity',
          width: 80,
          cellsalign: 'right'
      }, {
          text: 'Unit Price',
          datafield: 'price',
          width: 90,
          cellsalign: 'right',
          cellsformat: 'c2'
      }, 
     
      
      {
          text: 'Total',
          datafield: 'total',
          width: 100,
          cellsalign: 'right',
          cellsformat: 'c2'
      }]
  });
  
   $('#jqxbutton').click(function () {
    var rows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrows');
  
     var selectedRows = rows.filter(x => x.available)
     
    console.log(selectedRows)
   
     //alert(rows);
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<div id="jqxgrid"></div>
<input type="button" style="margin: 50px;" id="jqxbutton" value="Get rows" />
```

**Edited: Testing for the default value of `2016` and `aggregate` based on Calculuswhiz's answer:**

```js
let firstNames = [
  "Andrew", "Nancy", "Shelley", "Regina", "Yoshi", "Antoni", "Mayumi", "Ian", 
  "Peter", "Lars", "Petra", "Martin", "Sven", "Elio", "Beate", "Cheryl", "Michael", "Guylene"
];

let lastNames = [
  "Fuller", "Davolio", "Burke", "Murphy", "Nagase", "Saavedra", "Ohno", 
  "Devling", "Wilson", "Peterson", "Winkler", "Bein", "Petersen", "Rossi", 
  "Vileid", "Saylor", "Bjorn", "Nodier"
];

let yearEligible = [
  "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N"
];

let productNames = [
  "Black Tea", "Green Tea", "Caffe Espresso", "Doubleshot Espresso", 
  "Caffe Latte", "White Chocolate Mocha", "Cramel Latte", "Caffe Americano", 
  "Cappuccino", "Espresso Truffle", "Espresso con Panna", "Peppermint Mocha Twist"
];

let priceValues = [
  "2.25", "1.5", "3.0", "3.3", "4.5", "3.6", "3.8", "2.5", "5.0", "1.75", "3.25", "4.0"
];

let data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  let productindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * productNames.length);
  let price = parseFloat(priceValues[productindex]);
  let quantity = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
  let row = {
    firstname : firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)],
    lastname : lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)],
    yeareligible : yearEligible[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)],
    productname : productNames[productindex],
    available : !!(i % 2),
    price : price,
    quantity : quantity,
    total : price * quantity
  };
  data.push(row);
}

let source = {
  localdata: data,
  datatype: "array"
};

let dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source,
{
  loadComplete: function(data) {},
  loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {}
});

$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
{
  theme: 'energyblue',
  width: 500,
  autoheight: true,
  editable: true,
  source: dataAdapter,
  columns: [{
      text: 'Available',
      datafield: 'available',
      width: 100,
      columntype: 'checkbox'
      
    }, {
      text: 'First Name',
      datafield: 'firstname',
      width: 100
    }, {
      text: 'Last Name',
      datafield: 'lastname',
      width: 100
    }, {
      text: 'Year Eligible',
      datafield: 'yeareligible',
      width: 100
    },
    {
      text: 'Year',
      width: 120,
      datafield: 'yearValue',
      columntype: 'dropdownlist',
      editable: true,
      createeditor: function(row, column, editor) 
      {
        let list = [
          '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', 
          '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021'
        ];
        editor.jqxDropDownList({
          autoDropDownHeight: true,
          source: list,
          selectedIndex: 0
        });
      },
      cellsrenderer : (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) =>
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', row).yeareligible === 'N'
          ? '<p>N/A</p>'
          : defaulthtml
    },
    {
      text: 'Product',
      datafield: 'productname',
      width: 180
    }, {
      text: 'Quantity',
      datafield: 'quantity',
      width: 80,
      cellsalign: 'right'
    }, {
      text: 'Unit Price',
      datafield: 'price',
      width: 90,
      cellsalign: 'right',
      cellsformat: 'c2'
    },
    {
      text: 'Total',
      datafield: 'total',
      width: 100,
      cellsalign: 'right',
      cellsformat: 'c2'
    }
  ]
});

// Addendum for OP's purposes
// Set default year to 2016 if available is checked
$("#jqxgrid").on('cellvaluechanged', function (evt)
{
  let args = evt.args;
  if (args.datafield === 'available' && args.newvalue)
  {
    let rowData = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', args.rowindex);
    if (rowData.yeareligible === 'N')
      return;
      
    $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('setcellvalue', args.rowindex, 'yearValue', 2016);
  }
});

$('#jqxbutton').click(function() 
{ 
    
  let rows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrows');
  let selectedRows = rows
let count = selectedRows.filter(x => x.available).length;
console.log("Printing selected rows/count length");
  console.log(count);

    rows.filter(x => x.available)
    .map(x => 
      x.yeareligible === 'N'
        ? Object.assign({}, x, {yearValue : '-1'}) 
        : Object.assign({}, {yearValue : '2016'}, x)
    );
  
  console.log(selectedRows);
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<div id="jqxgrid"></div>
<input type="button" style="margin: 50px;" id="jqxbutton" value="Get rows" />
```

Answer (score 1):

- To show `N/A` for the year column, you can use a custom `cellsrenderer` for the `yearValue` column:

  ```
  cellsrenderer : (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) =>
    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', row).yeareligible === 'N'
      ? '<p>N/A</p>'
      : defaulthtml
  ```

  The `cellsrenderer` returns the new raw html you want to display in the cell without overwriting the underlying value. Unfortunately, you cannot return an element or JQuery object, but for simple html, it works OK.
- To add `yearValue : -1` to `selectedRows`, you can use `map()` and `Object.assign()` to return a merged object.

  ```
  let rows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrows');
  let selectedRows = rows
    .filter(x => x.available)
    .map(x => 
      x.yeareligible === 'N'
        ? Object.assign({}, x, {yearValue : '-1'}) 
        : x
    );
  ```

  The API doesn't have a function to override the cell value returned by any of the getter methods. There is a way to override the editor value (`geteditorvalue`), but that requires that the value be set at least once via the cell's editor, which is not created until the cell is edited for the first time. If that doesn't happen, `geteditorvalue` will not called, so you'd end up having to write a similar map function in the end anyway.

  Note that this will always add the `yearvalue: '-1'` whenever `yeareligible` is `'N'`, so you may want to put an additional check for `yearvalue != null`. Or you may want to consider whether adding the value is necessary at all since `yeareligible` already tells you the information you need.

---

Putting it all together:

```js
let firstNames = [
  "Andrew", "Nancy", "Shelley", "Regina", "Yoshi", "Antoni", "Mayumi", "Ian", 
  "Peter", "Lars", "Petra", "Martin", "Sven", "Elio", "Beate", "Cheryl", "Michael", "Guylene"
];

let lastNames = [
  "Fuller", "Davolio", "Burke", "Murphy", "Nagase", "Saavedra", "Ohno", 
  "Devling", "Wilson", "Peterson", "Winkler", "Bein", "Petersen", "Rossi", 
  "Vileid", "Saylor", "Bjorn", "Nodier"
];

let yearEligible = [
  "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N"
];

let productNames = [
  "Black Tea", "Green Tea", "Caffe Espresso", "Doubleshot Espresso", 
  "Caffe Latte", "White Chocolate Mocha", "Cramel Latte", "Caffe Americano", 
  "Cappuccino", "Espresso Truffle", "Espresso con Panna", "Peppermint Mocha Twist"
];

let priceValues = [
  "2.25", "1.5", "3.0", "3.3", "4.5", "3.6", "3.8", "2.5", "5.0", "1.75", "3.25", "4.0"
];

let data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  let productindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * productNames.length);
  let price = parseFloat(priceValues[productindex]);
  let quantity = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
  let row = {
    firstname : firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)],
    lastname : lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)],
    yeareligible : yearEligible[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)],
    productname : productNames[productindex],
    available : !!(i % 2),
    price : price,
    quantity : quantity,
    total : price * quantity
  };
  data.push(row);
}

let source = {
  localdata: data,
  datatype: "array"
};

let dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source,
{
  loadComplete: function(data) {},
  loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {}
});

$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
{
  theme: 'energyblue',
  width: 500,
  autoheight: true,
  editable: true,
  source: dataAdapter,
  columns: [{
      text: 'Available',
      datafield: 'available',
      width: 100,
      columntype: 'checkbox'
    }, {
      text: 'First Name',
      datafield: 'firstname',
      width: 100
    }, {
      text: 'Last Name',
      datafield: 'lastname',
      width: 100
    }, {
      text: 'Year Eligible',
      datafield: 'yeareligible',
      width: 100
    },
    {
      text: 'Year',
      width: 120,
      datafield: 'yearValue',
      columntype: 'dropdownlist',
      editable: true,
      createeditor: function(row, column, editor) 
      {
        let list = [
          '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', 
          '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021'
        ];
        editor.jqxDropDownList({
          autoDropDownHeight: true,
          source: list,
          selectedIndex: 0
        });
      },
      cellsrenderer : (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) =>
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', row).yeareligible === 'N'
          ? '<p>N/A</p>'
          : defaulthtml
    },
    {
      text: 'Product',
      datafield: 'productname',
      width: 180
    }, {
      text: 'Quantity',
      datafield: 'quantity',
      width: 80,
      cellsalign: 'right'
    }, {
      text: 'Unit Price',
      datafield: 'price',
      width: 90,
      cellsalign: 'right',
      cellsformat: 'c2'
    },
    {
      text: 'Total',
      datafield: 'total',
      width: 100,
      cellsalign: 'right',
      cellsformat: 'c2'
    }
  ]
});

// Addendum for OP's purposes
// Set default year to 2016 if available is checked
$("#jqxgrid").on('cellvaluechanged', function (evt)
{
  let args = evt.args;
  if (args.datafield === 'available' && args.newvalue)
  {
    let rowData = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', args.rowindex);
    if (rowData.yeareligible === 'N')
      return;
      
    $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('setcellvalue', args.rowindex, 'yearValue', 2016);
  }
});

$('#jqxbutton').click(function() 
{
  let rows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrows');
  let selectedRows = rows
    .filter(x => x.available)
    .map(x => 
      x.yeareligible === 'N'
        ? Object.assign({}, x, {yearValue : '-1'}) 
        : x
    );

  console.log(selectedRows);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<div id="jqxgrid"></div>
<input type="button" style="margin: 50px;" id="jqxbutton" value="Get rows" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. Few more questions, 1) Is it possible to display/show jqxdropdown list existence without having the user click on the cell, especially for the `Year` column where Year Eligible is `Y`? In this way, user would know that there is something to click. 2) Also,  Iwas wondering if I ca nshow a default value in the Year column if a user doesn't select anything? For example, maybe 2016 by default shows up on the screen so that a default value always goes with the selection if user doesn't select anything.

Comment: @Tan 1) Yes. You can modify the `cellsrenderer` callback. Instead of returning `defaulthtml`, you can return `\`<p>${value || '[Choose Year]'}</p>\``. 2) In `createeditor`, add an event listener to `editor` for the `'close'` event. Then if `editor.val()` is blank, select `2016`.

Comment: 1) Works fine. For #2) - I didn't understand this line 
`In createeditor, add an event listener to editor for the 'close' event. Then if editor.val() is blank, select `. What's the significance of `close` event here as I want to get the default value of `2016` when a user checkmarks the row which has `Year Eligible` as `Y` and I should be able to get the value of `2016` by default and if user selects something else then it should be that value. Thanks again !

Comment: @Tan Oh, I misunderstood. I thought you meant if the user clicks out of the menu without making a selection. Sure, that's easy. Use the `cellvaluechanged` event and check that it's the correct field. See latest edit for example.

Comment: Thanks. After running your edited snippet, I noticed that the `yearValue` is missing from the console log statement. For example, the following `console.log` shows that I selected a record and didn't select anything from the dropdow. But it doesn't include `yearValue: 2016`.  Including my `console.log` result as  a separate comment. Please let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: `[
  {
    "firstname": "Petra",
    "lastname": "Nagase",
    "yeareligible": "Y",
    "productname": "Peppermint Mocha Twist",
    "available": true,
    "price": 4,
    "quantity": 9,
    "total": 36,
    "uid": 1,
    "boundindex": 1,
    "uniqueid": "3023-24-31-19-191619",
    "visibleindex": 1
  }
]`

Comment: @Tan If you want to infer a default value of 2016 from a blank, you can modify the map function. Instead of returning `x`, return `Object.assign({}, {yearValue : '2016'}, x)`. This assigns an automatic value of 2016, which can get overwritten if the user selects a year.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237193/discussion-between-tan-and-calculuswhiz).